# Null Coalesce in parenthesis, in an if() Does this work as (I) expected?

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

I'm just wondering if this works, using a null coalesce, in an if() statement.

With no query string, this gives me a Warning: Undefined array key:

```
    if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar'){ 
        doAThing();
    }
```

whereas

```
    if(($_GET['foo'] ?? 0) == 'bar'){ 
        doAThing();
    }
```

seems to work. Just hoping there's not some weird gotcha.

I also noticed that you can assign the value, to the previously null variable:

```
    if(($_GET['foo'] ??= false) == 'bar'){ 
        doAThing();
    }
    $a = $_GET['foo'];//now equals false, no warning
```

Which is cool, cuz now you can use `$_GET['foo']` without testing for null or null coalesce.

Comment: Of course it works. You can put any expression in the `if` condition.

Comment: It is a thing that you can do, but it is generally frowned upon to alter the `$_*` superglobals.

Comment: That's true. It's more common to assign it to another variable, and use null coalescing when assigning. Then test the variable.

Comment: `$foo = $_GET['foo'] ?? 0;` then `if ($foo == 'bar')`

Comment: And if you do prefer assigning the superglobal, do it before the `if`, it will be clearer.

Comment: Ah, yes, dont mess with the superglobals. Thanks.

Comment: I'd write it as `if (isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == 'bar') { doAThing(); }`